# VS Code debugger shows incorrect value with jest test

Tags: vscode-debugger, ts-jest

I am trying to develop/debug API tests with typescript/jest, using VS Code.  I generally start with something like the following, set a break point at the console.log() statement, then use the debugger to examine the response and develop the remaining assertions.  The problem is that the debugger returns the wrong answer.  With the first bit of code, the debugger tells me that the value of `response` is 200. The screen shot shows different answers for local and watch values of response.

```
it ('should do something', () => {
    return axios.get('http://www.google.com')
    .then ((response: any) => {
        expect(response.status).toEqual(200)
        console.log('xxxx')
    })
})
```

[image]

With this bit of code, taking axios/promises/etc. out of the equation, setting a breakpoint at the first console.log statement and evaluating "data" shows the correct value.  A breakpoint at the second console.log statement shows the value of `data.x` when evaluating data.

```
it ('should do something', async ()=> {
    const data = {"x":[{"Id":1,"Name":"One","Type":"thing"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Two","Type":"stuff"}]}
    console.log('1111')
    console.log(data.x[0].Id)
    console.log ('2222')
})
```

The problem seems to be specific to jest. I've tried an identical test with mocha/chai, and the debugger always shows the correct value.  How can I get the debugger to give me correct answers when using jest?

This is the relevant entry in launch.json, if it has any impact on answers.

```
{
    "name": "Jest API Tests, Current",
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "runtimeArgs": [
        "--inspect-brk",
        "node_modules/.bin/jest",
        "--runInBand",
        "--testTimeout=9999999",
        "--testMatch=${file}"
    ],
    "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/API-Testing",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/.p4d-adf",
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you install the [jest VS Code extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Orta.vscode-jest), debugging works exactly as expected.